# Two sentences with a tricky article

Tags: articles

Where I spend most of my time these days.
or
Where I spend the most of my time these days.

Property is theft.
or
Property is a theft.

[Google ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=property%20is%20theft,%20property%20is%20a%20theft&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) favours "Property is theft," but why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Most** v **the most***
In *most of my time* the *most of* piece is not a noun, but a quantifier like *some of* or *all of* applied to *time*. It doesn't require a determiner because a quantifier already is a determiner.

***The** most* is usually employed when you are comparing quantities:

> He has much, she has more, but I have the most.
>   Of the three of us, I have the most.

***Property is theft***
This is a quotation from Proudhon. In the original French it is *La propriété, c'est le vol !* The first article there signals in French usage that Proudhon is speaking of an abstraction, the institution of property, and the second article is a witty parallelism, insinuating that, first, he is speaking of the abstract crime, not a specific instance, and, second, that stealing is thus institutionalized.

But in English we express such abstractions with no article, marked with Ø below:

> Ø Property is the foundation of civilization.
>   Ø Theft is defined in the Uniform Criminal Code.

With an article, one speaks of a specific instance of the abstraction:

> My ownership of a piece of land is ***a*** theft from the community.
>   He was sent to the galleys for ***the*** theft of a loaf of bread.

Comment: Weird! Not 30 seconds ago I read an answer by you that referenced a literary work. For some reason I had the fleeting thought then that I would soon see a Les Miserables reference from you. Freaky to see that reference ("He was sent to the galleys for the theft of a loaf of bread" for anyone who might wonder what I'm talking about) now, less than a minute later! :)

Answer (score 2):

*Most* requires the article ('the') when it is being used as a superlative. For example:

> The most popular band is ...
>
> My dog has the loudest bark

Otherwise you don't need to use 'the':

> Most people have the ability to read and write
>
> I feel sick most of the time

In the second example, the use of theft is not referring to an individual act of thievery, but the concept of stealing as a whole.  This could be reworded as:

The concept of *property* is equivalent to the concept of *theft*.

Answer (score 0):

*The* is not used when *most* means, "more than half of somebody/something; almost all of somebody/something."

> I like most vegetables.

> Most of the people I had invited turned up.

*The* can be left out in informal British English, when *most* means, "the largest in number or amount."

> Who do you think will get (the) most votes?

> She had the most money of all of them.